# Hidden footer space on cell phones

Tags: html, css

I have what I find a very weird problem, so I'm going to show you how to replicate.  If you use google chrome and go to http://tiu.azularis.com/Contact.  Setup your browser to emulate a samson Galaxy S4 by pressing F12 and then clicking on the square icon at the top left corner of the F12 menu.  Now refresh the page so that it shows in mobile view.  Highlight over the HTML text and look at the height.  It shows 1742 pixels.  However there is a square block of another 100 pixels below it which is coming out of nowhere.

I can't find a way to get rid of it, setting html and body to `height: 100%` or `min-height: 100%` does not works.  Any suggestions?

I also tried to set body as `position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;` and that had no effect.

Here is the screenshot, take note of the section below the highlighted part:
http://postimg.org/image/e3j7m80rv/

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "another 100 pixels below it." Do you mean the padding at the bottom of the content?

Comment: it was a rough guess of pixels as I can't even select that area.  Hmm let me edit my main post and give you a screenshot.

Comment: Not anything to do with your page height, but please turn off the JS showing the height popup.

Comment: sorry about that, its off now.  What does it have to do?  how do I overcome it?  On the actual cell phone it doesn't show the black bar it shows chopped up parts form my site, it looks really bad.

Comment: If you set html to something like 105%, the background image covers the full screen.  Why?  No idea at the moment.

Comment: @sideroxylon that can be my fallback if I can't figure it out.  What I've discovered is that if the page is under about 1900 px then it creates this problem, I don't get it.

Comment: Maybe try changing your javascript so that you get screen height instead of window height when re-sizing the html.

Comment: tried it, that doesn't work either.  I removed the javascript for now.  I was going to use it out of desperation, but I would really like a css solution if possible.

Comment: Tried adding this: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable = no">` to the head?

Comment: The website was not designed to be responsive, so adding that would create a problem no?  I have not tried that for those reasons, I think that is only when the website is responsive and you want to force the width of the pages to be device's width.  Correct me if I am wrong, but that is my understanding.